# How to use SSH authentication on git

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys, personal-access-token

I am trying to git push and its bringing out this error:

> remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
>
> remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/OwoJama/myproject4.git/'

I tried pushing a commit to my remote repository but it won't fly as it pop's out the error above. I later realized password authentication has been discontinued and I will want to know how to use the ssh key authentication method to log in.

Comment: Have you gone through github's documentation?  Last time I checked they give you the exact commands to run.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remote%3A+Support+for+password+authentication+was+removed+on+August+13%2C+2021 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bssh%5D+%5Bssh-keys%5D+generate+key